# Accessing Subclass Attribute from Super Class

Tags: jsf, inheritance, attributes, primefaces

have two classes, A and B, where B extends A and has one attribute that is not present in A.

In my Managed Bean, I keep an instance of A, that can be of type B or not, depending on what the user selects on the page.

In my xhtml page, sometimes I have to do something like `#{myBean.A.attribute}`, where 'attribute' is only present in class B. Because of that, the component (or a parent) that tries to access this attribute must have something like `rendered="#{myBean.isTypeBSelected()}"`.

It was working flawlessly and for some reason it started to throw PropertyNotFoundException, because it was trying to access the attribute even when the component (or a parent) was evaluating to rendered="false".

Full stacktrace:

```
14:39:54,142 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-3) /restrito/formularios/formularios.xhtml @340,63 value="#{formularioMB.perguntaSelecionada.opcoesResposta}": The class 'br.ind.seat.pso.modelo.PerguntaTexto' does not have the property 'opcoesResposta'.: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /restrito/formularios/formularios.xhtml @340,63 value="#{formularioMB.perguntaSelecionada.opcoesResposta}": The class 'br.ind.seat.pso.modelo.PerguntaTexto' does not have the property 'opcoesResposta'.
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:773) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1798) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:1401) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener.resetEditableValueHolders(ResetInputAjaxActionListener.java:229) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
at org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener.access$000(ResetInputAjaxActionListener.java:107) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
at org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener$1.visit(ResetInputAjaxActionListener.java:241) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1612) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener.resetEditableValueHolders(ResetInputAjaxActionListener.java:229) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
at org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener.processAction(ResetInputAjaxActionListener.java:174) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at br.ind.seat.pso.filtros.FiltroUrlPattern.doFilter(FiltroUrlPattern.java:44) [classes:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at br.ind.seat.pso.filtros.FiltroNoCache.doFilter(FiltroNoCache.java:46) [classes:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at br.ind.seat.pso.filtros.FiltroDePermissao.doFilter(FiltroDePermissao.java:45) [classes:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at br.ind.seat.pso.filtros.FiltroUsuarioLogado.doFilter(FiltroUsuarioLogado.java:44) [classes:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I did what you said, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my fault for adding a `<p: messages />` inside my `<p:dialog />`.
Because of that, even with my dialog being set to `dynamic="true"`, the `<p: messages />` inside it was forcing it to load.

I solved it by setting `autoUpdate="false"` in the `<p: messages/>`.